# Child state with optional parameter and query String together angular js

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, query-string, optional-parameters

I have this child state.. where I want my url to be either one of these:
`/:case/:recordId` or
`/:case?tabs=0`

Hitting the second url with this state makes the state redirect to the previous url and the query params removes from the url.I want the query param to stay.

Is it possible to have either a state param (/) or a query param (?) in a single state url?

```
.state('business/overview/record', {
    url: '/:case/:recordId',
    parent: 'business/overview',
    params: {
        recordId: {
            squash: true
        }
    }
})
```